# preg_match parenthesized pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to change a bunch of decimals in a string to two decimal points. The regex seems to match it just fine. The problem is with the replace.

This is my code:

```
$input_lines = "-33.873293252 151.201538015999972,-33.873175 151.201689183999946";

print preg_replace("/[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/", "$0 $2", $input_lines);
```

Which outputs *decimal that I want* | *truncated decimals that I don't want*:

```
 -33.87 3293252  151.20 1538015999972 ,-33.87 3175  151.20 1689183999946
```

So I tried changing the `replacement` to `$0`. But now the replace stopped working, and is instead giving me:

```
-33.873293252 151.201538015999972,-33.873175 151.201689183999946
```

How can I rewrite my regular expression so it gives me the desired output?

Comment: What's your expected output? And where comes the `$2`  since your regex contains a single capturing group ?

Comment: i assume split on `/[\s,]/` and `round(number, 2)` each would be silly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better:

```
preg_replace("/(?<=\.\d\d)\d+/","",$input_lines);
```

Replaces all trailing decimals after the first two with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)(\d*)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/46

```
$re = "/([-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d{2})?)(\\d*)/m";
$str = "-33.873293252 151.201538015999972,-33.873175 151.201689183999946";
$subst = "$1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```